# Pass Arguments to HAML Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Using rails 3.2.11, and whatever the newest version of HAML is, I've been trying to pass a block to a HAML partial. I suppose I could use a variable in the HAML file, and then assign that variable before I render the partial, but that feels really sloppy and rigid.

I noticed that in the rails application layout, there is a `= yield`, which is clearly where all my views get rendered. Is there a way for me to cleanly use arguments and blocks in my HAML partials?

Comment: can you share some code that might help with figuring out what you want.  Are you trying out the example shown here?http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-_layout_for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass whatever you'd like to a partial. You can use something like this:

```
= render "people/person", :object => @manager, :locals => { :show_details => true }
```

You can also use yield and content_for together to handle blocks. If you do something like:

```
- content_for :profile_links do
  %li Hello #{@manager.name}
  %li= link_to "Settings", @manager.profile
```

And then yield that in your account menu with:

```
%ul#account_menu
  = yield :profile_links
  %li= link_to "Sign Out", sign_out_url
```